# Is it possible to one-to-one relationship can have one-to-many relation?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

Think about 3 actors of a database system. Student,teacher and parent. Their attributes are exactly same name, surname, contact, etc. So  let's assume I wanted to keep them in one table as user and give them a role. So I have 2 tables now user and roles table. I assume these 2 table has one-to-one relationship. And there is one more thing. A parent can have multiple students as their childs. Is it possible to have one-to-many relationship from these user and role table or how can I manage this situation in best way?

**EDIT**

[image: Student,Parent and Teacher]

This is the tables of student,user and teacher. Like you notice they have same attributes. I want to design the more  efficient way because they have sam attributes plus parent can have multiple student.

Comment: A user and a roles table are not sufficient, because you must assign a user A in role B to a user C in role D, for example: Student Mary has teacher John (A = Mary, B = student, C = John, D = teacher).

Comment: You might want to consider a self join to describe a relationship between parent, teachers and students

Comment: 1:1 relationship between user and role would mean that each user has its own role. In reality, what you describe is a 1:n relationship as there will be multiple persons in each role. However, real life situations can cause even further complications: what if a parent becomes a student or a teacher decides to send their children to the same school where they teach? I admit that these are edge cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a third table called "Relationships" (or whatever you want to call it) that would have attributes: firstPerson, relationship, secondPerson.

There's a phrase to represent this, it goes something like:

> It's not mine neither it's yours, It's something between us

That means, the role is neither relative to one user or the other, it's something they share, so it should be in a differente table

So you would have something like:

Users table:

```
id      name         surname
1       Mary         Smith
2       John         Doe
3       Charles      Smith
```

Roles table:

```
id      description
1       teacher
2       student
3       parent
```

Relationships table:

```
firstUserId        roleId       secondUserId
3(Charles)         3(parent)    1(Mary)
2(John)            1(teacher)   1(Mary)
1(Mary)            2(student)   2(John)
```

Comment: From a database design point of view, this answer is correct. From a semantics point of view, however, is not. It is rare that teachers are directly teach students. Teachers teach certain classes and students attend certain classes. A teacher for a class can be replaced by another teacher during the course.

Comment: You are completely right, we should have a Classes table too.